# Creating a new txt file with a PHP function

Tags: php, file, function

I am trying to write a function that takes two parameters (the filename and a sting to put inside) that creates a new file, containing the string.

```
<?php

function writeFile($name, $string) {
    $text = $string;
    $fh = fopen($name + ".txt", 'w') or die("Could not create the file.");
    fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to the file.");
    fclose($fh);
    echo "File " . $name . ".txt created!";
}

writeFile("testovFail", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");

if(file_exists("testovFail.txt")) echo "<br>File exists!";

?>
```

This is what I have so far, the function echos that the file was created, but when I run the IF conditional to check whether the file was created, it returns that it wasn't.

Comment: Have a look at `file_put_contents()` - it does that same as `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`. You should also check the return of `fwrite()` (and `file_put_contents()` if you use it). http://php.net/file_put_contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this : `fopen($name . ".txt", 'w')` 
$name + ".txt" always returns 0 !

Answer (score 5):

how about using [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead?

```
$current = "John Smith";
file_put_contents("blabla.txt", $current);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$name + ".txt"` This is not how [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) works in php. It should be `$name.'txt'`.

Your code as is will create file with the name `0` because it adds value of `$name` (which is `string` in given example) to `string` and `(int)'somestring' === 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function writeFile($name, $string) {
    $filename = $name.".txt"; 
    $text = "helloworld"; 
    $fp = fopen($filename,"a+");  
    fputs($fp,$string); 
    fclose($fp);  
}
```

This should do it - hope it does so far.
With +w you would delete the content witch is already in your file and with a+ it will append it to the text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach. :)

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt', 'w');
$file->fwrite('Hi!');
```